# Вырезать только первые N строк таблицы

Tags: php

Есть строка с текстом:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Тип:</td>
            <td>Дом из бруса</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Общая площадь объекта</td>
            <td>131,9 м2 м<sup>2</sup></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Жилая площадь объекта</td>
            <td>77 м2 м<sup>2</sup></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Срок строительства 30 дней</td>
            <td>(?)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Терраса</td>
            <td>Да</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Каким образом вырезать только первые 3 **tr** ?

То есть чтобы в конечном итоге осталось только:

```
        <tr>
            <td>Тип:</td>
            <td>Дом из бруса</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Общая площадь объекта</td>
            <td>131,9 м2 м<sup>2</sup></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Жилая площадь объекта</td>
            <td>77 м2 м<sup>2</sup></td>
        </tr>
```

Учитывая то что текст в блоках  всегда разный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну как вариант... Конечно не самый оптимальный:

```
$TEXT = '
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Тип:</td>
            <td>Дом из бруса</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Общая площадь объекта</td>
            <td>131,9 м2 м<sup>2</sup></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Жилая площадь объекта</td>
            <td>77 м2 м<sup>2</sup></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Срок строительства 30 дней</td>
            <td>(?)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Терраса</td>
            <td>Да</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
';

preg_match_all("|(<tr>(.*)</tr>)|isU", $TEXT, $OUT, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

$OUT = array_slice($OUT[1], 0, 3);
$OUT = implode('', $OUT);
var_dump($OUT);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr=explode('</tr>',$str);
$str=$arr[0].'</tr>'.$arr[1].'</tr>'.$arr[2].'</tr>';
```